# Creating a route to accept two parameters for specific controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this controller method in my FilesController:

```
public ActionResult Download(int id, string filename)
{
    var file = _filesRepository.GetFile(id);

    // Write it back to the client
    Response.ContentType = file.FileMimeType;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.FileName);
    Response.BinaryWrite(file.FileData);

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

This works if I navigate to

> /Files/Download/123?filename=myimage.png

But I'd like it work if I navigate to

> /Files/Download/123/myimage.png

I know I need to create a custom route for this, but everything I've tried isn't working. I'd like it to accept two parameters for only the FilesController and Download method. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is very easy if you create a new route.  In your `Global.asax.cs` file, before the default route, add the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "FileDownload", // Route name
  "Files/Download/{id}/{filename}", // URL with parameters
  new { 
    controller = "Files", 
    action = "Download", 
    id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
    filename = UrlParameter.Optional 
  } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Then your controller action should work as you currently have it defined.